# Automatically go to subdirectory index page .htaccess rule

Tags: php, web

I want that when I click on a link like this: `<a href="settings/">Settings</a>` it will go to the subdirectory, and load `index.php`.
When I try this right now I get a `404 error`

It works if the link is as so: `<a href="settings/index.php">Settings</a>` but I don't want `index.php` in the url.

Does anybody know how can I write an `.htaccess` rule to achieve this ?

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This should be the default behaviour for apache, unless you already have rewrite rules in place.

Comment: Any idea how to write the rewrite rules for this?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html Look at the `DirectoryIndex` directive ^^

Comment: How do you want it to go to the file if you do not specify the correct route?

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus because I know it's possible to achieve this by modifying the .htaccess or something, that is what I am looking for help with

Comment: If your web server is apache, you're almost certainly in need of simply adding a new directive `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky just gave you the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh you just mentioned `.htaccess`, now i can answer.  You just need to edit your `DirectoryIndex` directive. Add this to your `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

I added a comment before answering because you didn't specify the web server. After your comment mentioning `.htaccess` its surely apache and this solution is for apache. You can either edit your config file or add that to your `.htaccess`

This directive tells apache to use `index.php` as the directory index first and if it cant find that then look for `index.html`

Comment: This works only when I take out what I had previously in the `.htaccess` something must be conflicting, and I don't know much about the `.htaccess` yet, I updated my question to include what is in the htaccess if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: Your rewrite condition is incomplete. Add directory check to it as well.  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: So you will have one new line below the existing `RewriteCond` line.

Comment: Works great, much appreciated!